# Is there any way to make Windows traverse files faster

Tags: c++, windows

I'm working on an photo management project recently,one function is to scan JPG files,and I used `boost::filesystem::recursive_directory_iterator` with `std::unordered_multimap` but the performance is very poor.

with indexing:

```
[2022-08-10 14:11:48.556] [debug] 16.837325 seconds,969178 files,57561 files per second
```

without indexing:

```
[2022-08-10 14:13:47.389] [debug] 66.298863 seconds,732820 files,11053 files per second
```

My code is here:

```
    uint64_t count = 0;
    auto start = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();

    std::unordered_multimap<std::wstring, std::wstring> type_map{};
    boost::filesystem::recursive_directory_iterator end_iter;
    for (boost::filesystem::recursive_directory_iterator iter(L"\\\\.\\F:\\", boost::filesystem::directory_options::skip_permission_denied); iter != end_iter; iter++)
    {
        type_map.emplace(iter->path().extension().c_str(), iter->path().c_str());
        ++count;
    }

    auto end = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    auto duration = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(end - start);
    auto time = (double)duration.count() * std::chrono::microseconds::period::num / std::chrono::microseconds::period::den;
    spdlog::debug("{} seconds,{} files,{} files per second", time, count, (uint64_t)(count / time));

    auto range = type_map.equal_range(L".jpg");
    for (auto iter = range.first; iter != range.second; ++iter)
    {
        spdlog::info(L"found {}", iter->second);
    }
```

msbuild parameters are:

```
/permissive- /Yu"stdafx.h" /ifcOutput "x64\Release\" /GS /GL /W3 /Gy /Zc:wchar_t /Zi /Gm- /O2 /sdl /Fd"x64\Release\vc143.pdb" /FI"stdafx.h" /Zc:inline /fp:precise /D "NDEBUG" /D "_CONSOLE" /D "_UNICODE" /D "UNICODE" /errorReport:prompt /WX- /Zc:forScope /std:c17 /Gd /Oi /MT /std:c++latest /FC /Fa"x64\Release\" /EHsc /nologo /Fo"x64\Release\" /Fp"x64\Release\jpg_searcher.pch" /diagnostics:column
```

Comment: In `type_map.emplace(iter->path().extension().c_str(), iter->path().c_str());` you should be able to avoid getting the c-style string from `extension` and `path` with the [`wstring`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_63_0/libs/filesystem/doc/reference.html#wstring) methods. Don't think that'll speed things up appreciably, but you never know. It is a few less behind-the scenes steps.

Comment: Have you determined/measured where your bottlneck is? (Is the disk a HDD or SDD?).  For performance measurements always use release builds. And why don't you use https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem.

Comment: @user4581301 I replaced it with ```type_map.emplace(std::move(iter->path().extension().wstring()), std::move(iter->path().wstring()));```,and I tried it again,It improved some performance

Comment: @PepijnKramer Yes,std version DOES improved some performance

Comment: My comment on using std version was mostly because you will be less dependent on external libraries. (I have a policy to refactor code to std library when I see the opportunity). But nice it improves performance a bit too. Did you start testing release builds?

Comment: @PepijnKramer It's already release build

Comment: The bare metal WIN32 functions that underpin the search (FindFirstFileEx and FindNext) have a `FIND_FIRST_EX_LARGE_FETCH` flag, and that can increase performance markedly in my experience.  You also want to be sure that the optimal pattern to match against is being passed to `FindFirstFileEx` (although I'm not quite sure what that  would be).  All in all, you might do better rolling your own enumerator that calls these functions directly.

Comment: As an aside, in `std::move(iter->path().wstring())` the wstring already is an rvalue, so `std::move` doesn't do anything. Just redundant code.

Comment: @PaulSanders bare metal winapi is surely fast,but it contains a lot of C-style code,if there is a huge improvement on performance, I would consider using winapi

Comment: @BoP thanks,my visual studio have already pointed out!

Comment: @Mitsuha Only way to know is to try it...